# Makefile project - Preventing build failure when using multiple jobs via "-j" argument

Tags: c++, linux, makefile, gnu-make

I have a number of simple C++ Makefile projects using GNU Make style makefiles I've manually written, rather than using Automake or CMake. The most sophisticated mechanism in them is the use of `pkginfo` to get compile-time flags and include paths for a handful of third-party libraries.

I am able to greatly speed up my builds on my current hardware (Intel i7 quad core) via running make like, so, assuming 4 cores on the machine:

```
make -j5 -l4
```

However, some projects, which build fine when run serially (ie: j1), fail when I allow multiple jobs. These projects that fail are essentially a set of projects that are built in sequence from a "master" makefile, and certain dependencies are built out of order.

Assuming I have a list of projects like so:

```
library1 (all other projects depend on this)
library2 (all other projects depend on this)
library3 (some other projects depend on this)
example1
...
example20
```

Is there a simple/de-facto "standard" way of putting a marker/rule in place so that the master makefile builds the libraries first serially, then allows the remaining example projects to build in any which order?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you put the dependancies of the object files (*.o) into the make file? Can you post your Makefile as part of your question?

Comment: Your rules should be your dependencies- that's the whole idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe I didn't understand, but why don't you artificially declare library 2 to depend on library 1 in the master makefile, and library 3 to depend on 1 and 2, etc. Then it should only be possible for them to build serially.

I don't know if there's a special makefile language or option for this, would be keen to learn.